# curl command to upload file to form

Tags: firefox, curl, xpi

I'm trying to build a curl command that will upload my xpi to validation at [Mozilla Add-on Validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addon/validate).

I've captured the traffic with fiddler to see what the site is doing and try to mimic it's behavior from curl.

I've seen whats the post url, and tried `curl https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/standalone-upload --form 'upload=@path-to-xpi.xpi'` and also with `csrfmiddlewaretoken=@path-to-xpi.xpi`. And also tried adding the `Content-Type`.

This is the raw data from the first request:

`POST https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/standalone-upload HTTP/1.1
Host: addons.mozilla.org
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 41021
Origin: https://addons.mozilla.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryI0LeCjkeJnsfGipU
Accept: */*
Referer: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addon/validate
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.710702590.1450107779; sessionid=".eJyrVkouLkqLL8nPTs1TslLKznAOTYzI8czOTEzxCTe0SCzKichONjMO8PUO9Q5wcVfSUYpPLC3JiC8tTi2Kz0xRsjI0MrCwNDE3QZFISkwGmgeUVQJxi_Wg_GI9x9z8UKCIE1QeqKk4tbg4Mz8vPrWiILOoEmyepZmBQS0Aqsk0IA:1aLYVj:cbZQtNCkFRasDdFtJKI9b_WB6GA"`


`------WebKitFormBoundaryI0LeCjkeJnsfGipU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"`


`khCUaXlIkiadLW18arlXkc63PMKUKPDG
------WebKitFormBoundaryI0LeCjkeJnsfGipU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="extension.xpi"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream`

Currently I'm receiving an html page with Not allowed.

What am I missing? What else should I add to the request to receive a good response?

Thanks

Comment: There are cookies there that might hold a login-state for example. Your curl command probably needs to get those cookies in a first invoke, then do the upload.

Comment: You're right, thanks! I'll check that when I'll have time

Comment: the cookie that is probably important to include is `sessionid` because the other cookie is for google analytics tracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not resolving the curl upload command thing, but the original problem - **validate an xpi through command line.**

### Validating an xpi through command line

This can be achieved with the [addons-linter](https://github.com/mozilla/addons-linter) by Mozilla, which was in its early stages when this question was asked.